# declaring function with new keyword and self invoke it in javascript

Tags: javascript, function-constructor

I came across a code that look like this:

```
 const tempFunc = exp => {
  return new Function(`return ${exp}`)()
 }
```

first question:
is it self invoking the function and return it?.
what does tempFunc return exactly?

second question:
if we  call the function:

```
let result=tempFunc('3+2')
```

the result is 5.how does it convert the string and calculate the result?

Comment: That is very much the same as `eval`, but evaluates a single expression (because of the `return`). WARNING: this single-expression thing can be bypassed, don't use with insecure input!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Function

Comment: No self-invocation here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `tempFunc('3+2')` it returns `new Function("return 3+2")()`, which will create a function (`function() { return 3+2 };`) and then call that function.

Conversely, if `tempFunc` looked like this:

```js
const tempFunc = exp => {
  return new Function(`return ${exp}`);
 }
```

Then it would just return the new function uncalled and you'd have to call it separately: `tempFunc('3+2')();`

## Function Constructor

The function constructor (`new Function()`) is pretty interesting; you can basically tell it what arguments to expect as the first *n* arguments and the final argument is the function body. In your example, there are no arguments to our new function, but we could create one that takes arguments:

```js
const tempFunc = num => {
  return new Function('x', `return x + ${num}`)(2);
}

tempFunc(3);
// 5
```

Answer (score 0):

In case the arrow functions are confusing for you, you can also write it similar like this:

```
 const tempFunc = function(exp) {
  const compiledFunc = new Function(`return ${exp}`)
  return compiledFunc()
 }
```

This:

```
new Function(`return ${exp}`)
```

creates a new Function object with the submitted string. The string ("3+2" in your example) is compiled as a function as if it was javascript code. This Function object can then be called as if it was a normal javascript Function. Thats what the two paranthesis do at the end of the line:

```
return new Function(`return ${exp}`)() // <-- these call it
```

So if you call that tempFunc it runs the string as javascript code and returns it, quite similar to what `eval` does.